# C# - Using a Predicate to select a property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got a situation where I would like to pass the name of a property through a method as a parameter so that the method can invoke it.

I'm aware that I can do this with `Reflection`, but that's a bit overkill - and complicated, for what I want. So I explored a bit more and discovered the wonders of `Predicate<T>`.

This is basically what I'm angling to do, and keep in mind, this is like - the most rudimentary, quickly thrown together example possible;

```
public class ContainingParentClassWithProperties {
    public PackagedClassWithProperty OptionOne {
        get; set;
    } = new PackagedClassWithProperty {
        DesiredTargetProperty = "1"
    };

    public PackagedClassWithProperty OptionTwo {
        get; set;
    } = new PackagedClassWithProperty {
        DesiredTargetProperty = "2"
    };
}
```

Basic wrappers for a type of object that'll contain properties.

Then a method that can take them.

```
public void TryAcceptPredicateMethod(Predicate<ContainingParentClassWithProperties> p) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.DesiredTargetProperty);
}
```

And then using it;

```
public void TryCallAcceptPredicateMethod() {
    TryAcceptPredicateMethod(n => n.OptionOne);
}
```

I'm encountering two major problems;

1. "cannot convert lambda"

I get the following error when I try to call the method;

> Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

I honestly have no idea what this is saying. I'm not very versed in lambda expressions though;

2. Calling the intended propety

Trying to write out/call the property I'm aiming for just isn't working; It's telling me the `Predicate<ContainingParentClassWithProperties>` contains no definition of `DesiredTargetProperty`.

I'm pretty confused, overall. Can anyone help to clarify some of this, please?

Comment: Please read about [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) and [predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx). They are not designed for that.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect `Predicate<T>` to do? Because I think your confusion stems from the fact that you think it will do something for you, which it simply doesn't.

Comment: @DRKblade - I will read up on them, thank you.

Comment: @nvoigt Basically, I have a class that defines properties for various parts of the application. These properties change depending on whether the application is running local, or on a remote server. I need to be able to pass in the specific version of these properties through a DI container, and for some reason using `new` instances and just passing the objects as parameters is not working.

Comment: Why can't you have the same property and have your DIC load a different class depending on whether it's remote or local? You may want to ask your real question as a question, this seems to be more of an XY problem.

Comment: @DRKblade it's okay. You're both right. I'm using `Predicate` wrong. I __don't__ understand them. That's why I was asking. Thank you both very much for the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Predicate` for that. As in my comment, please learn more about predicates.

But here I think you can do like this

```
public void TryAcceptPredicateMethod(Func<PackagedClassWithProperty> p) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.DesiredTargetProperty);
}

public void TryCallAcceptPredicateMethod() {
    // n should be a variable or something in the type of ContainingParentClassWithProperties 
    TryAcceptPredicateMethod(() => n.OptionOne);
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed to accomplish, yes. I simply misunderstood what `Predicate` was for. `Func` seems to be completely suitable for what I need to do.

Comment: This turned out to work very well for several cases it was needed. Thank you again. I was able to restructure some code to just be outright better thanks to what I learned here.

Answer (score 0):

How about having properties defined as

```
public class PropertyContainingClass
{
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            if(isRunningLocal)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
    private bool isRunningLocal{ get; set; }
    public PropertyContainingClass()
    {
        this.isRunningLocal = //code to determine whether running local
    }
}
```

Class could be static if you like it that way